# Compile to multiple languages with a single .hxml file in Haxe

Tags: haxe, hxml

Here's the basic Haxe "Hello World!" program:

```
class Main 
{
    public static function main() 
    {
        trace("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Here's the build file for the above program:

```
-main Main
-java java
```

Now I want to compile this program to Java, Javascript, and C++ with a single .hxml file. How should the .hxml file be formatted, in this case?

Comment: It looks like the answer can be found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haxelang/9cswQ7f78as

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the command "--next" to specify the next compile target. So:

```
-main Main
-java java

--next

-main Main
-cpp cpp

--next
-flash out.swf
```

Answer (score 2):

I have written a `compile.hxml` file that compiles the class `Test.hx` to various target languages. All the necessary libraries will need to be installed first in order for it to work properly.

```
-js test.js
-main Test

--next
-php www
-main Test

--next
-cpp cpp
-debug
-main Test

--next
-main Test
-java java

--next
-cs test
-main Test
-D haxe3
```